# Software to detect intersections (within a tolerance) between 3d polylines

Tags: 3d, topology

Is there any way to detect intersections (within a tolerance) for a 3d set of polylines?

ArcGIS Topology Check seems to project everything into 2d (x-y plane) before checking, so shows a lot of false positives.

Autocad Map 3d Drawing Cleanup suffers from the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you look into PostGIS, using the function ST_3DDWithin, you would find a useful solution.

Comment: Thanks.  For a set of polylines rather than a single pair, efficiency becomes an issue - if I wanted to find all 3d intersections, do you know if the database implementation has an efficient way of searching for this, like Bentley-Ottmann or at least using bounding boxes?

Comment: I've found that for very long polylines, the bounding boxes can hinder the search.  Database tuning won't help much if your lines are huge and tangled like spaghetti, so I'd suggest breaking your polylines into smaller segments (going from say 1000m to 5m will help immensely), retaining the original identifier field (along with a new ID for just the segment).  Index your new geometries, and run off that new table.  Breaking polylines up into segments is a much faster process than I first thought it would be.  Of course this topic is larger than a comment can cover for every caveat.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure this needs to be said, but keep your original table.  The segmented table doesn't need to exist as anything more than a reference for positive join results.

Answer (score 1):

With ArcGIS, I suppose you have to use 3D Analyst but you have also free solutions:

- Postgis, as ikes says
- [GRASS GIS](http://grass.osgeo.org/) which is a true 3D GIS (look at [Visualization and volumetric 3D examples](http://grass.osgeo.org/screenshots/3D/) )
- [gvSIG](http://www.gvsig.org/web) can also manipulate 3D geometries
- and Python modules as [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html)

```py
from shapely.geometry import LineString  
line1 = LineString([[(0,2,5),(1,1,1),(5,4,3),(6,7,9)])  
line2 = LineString([[(1,2,4),(1,1,8),(3,5,6),(7,8,9)]])  
print line1  
LINESTRING Z (0 2 5, 1 1 1, 5 4 3, 6 7 9)  
line1.intersects(line2)  
True  
print line1.intersection(line2)  
POINT Z (1 1 1)
```

I am well aware that the problem is to transform ArcGIS geometries into PostGIS, GRASS GIS or Shapely geometries. There is no problem using 3D shapefiles (and not ESRI geodatabases)

Comment: I don't think the `interset 3d` tool in ArcGIS 3d analyst works with polylines.  The python idea is based on GEOS, which I have used: GEOS suffers from the same problem as ArcGIS (it's not true 3d and will project to the xy plane before intersecting).  Presumably shapely would do the same.  But I may well check out those others!

Comment: I agree, Shapely use GEOS, but GRASS GIS don't use GEOS